# Create xml from various cmdlets

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am currently trying to make a script that will perform various extraction extract from DCs and export to one xml file.

As someone completly new to the xml subject, I found this beautiful guide that answered my needs, to a point... [Custom XML from .NET PS](https://petri.com/creating-custom-xml-net-powershell?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_9JaVEBKVJdBWzE7wtVJugRlIaJlM_6089UOeQaTJIl4-1631174390-0-gqNtZGzNAfujcnBszQg9)

But, the script that is used in this guide seems to be compatible from PS Version 4.0, and what I need is something compatible from PS version 3.0 as some DCs are on 2008 SP1.

So what I'm looking for is if there's something that could be compatible for PS 3.0 and upward and still let me control the creation of the xml file freely and the way my results shows on the xml file as in the guide.

PS: I was to able to test the script on a 2008 SP1 server for lack of access, so the fact I'm saying it's not compatible is based on what is shown in the guide's script.

Comment: There's nothing in the sample scripts in that blog post that wouldn't work in WPS 3.0 - the CIM cmdlets used to gather the initial data were introduced in 3.0, and the relevant XML APIs are available as far back as 2.0. If you have _specific_ problems, please post the relevant snippets of code (and any error messages they might produce)

Comment: You *need* to show your code. It's no use to wave into the general direction of some tutorial. The tutorial might go away and then your question will lack all context. Show your code, show your expected result, show any errors you get.